# How to extract last name from /etc/passwd using awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

For example in /etc/passwd row 5 ($5) I have the name "Smith Simon". How can I extract the string "Simon" and store it using awk? Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the input text(without real passwords, of course)

Comment: I don't have input text. I have to work with /etc/passwd, and the names are in column 5.

Comment: There isn't a row number in /etc/passwd. The delimiter here is ":" and the user's names are stored in column 5($5). But I don't need the fullname of a user, only the last name.

Comment: You can't be sure about field 5 value. I put emails in there :)

Comment: @MattPhilips, What to do if name is having only "Smith" (no lastname) ?

Comment: @MattPhilips if you don't have input text then what do you need a script for since you've got nothing to run it against? I am stunned you're getting answers with no sample, input no expected output, and no attempted script - usually a question like this would've been closed in minutes! See [ask] for how to ask a question on this forum and then [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Ed Morton..I already wrote down numerous times that the input text is /etc/passwd file. Furthermore,I already got the answer/answers  (which I thank again) so you could easily skip this question and search for another "wrong question "which "would've been closed in minutes ".

Comment: You're absolutely right. Given your question I had the choice of telling you what was wrong with it so you could learn [ask] and so get more (and better!) answers here and to any future question you have or I could've just skipped it like everyone else who could haven helped you and just moved on instead. YMMV telling us to go look in our own /etc/password file for input file layout and pretend the text `Smith Simon` exists in it and figure out what to output if that text does, doesn't or partially appears (`Smith Simonson`, `Smith Simon Jones`, `Will Smith Simon`, etc.).

Comment: To be clear - your question is extremely vague and ambiguous. 1) `in /etc/passwd row 5 ($5)` - which do you mean, row 5 or column 5 ($5)? 2) `I have the name "Smith Simon". How can I extract the string "Simon" and store it using awk?` - so are you looking for that particular name or names that start with Simon or end with Smith or something else? 3) Do you want to get the last word from every 5th col or just from the 5th line or something else? The answers you got all make different assumptions about what you're asking and all of the vagueness would be cleared up by one clear [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> extract the string "Simon" and store it

***gawk*** approach:

```
firstname=$(awk -F':' '{split($5, s, " "); print s[2]}' /etc/passwd)
echo $firstname
Simon
```

---

`split($5, s, " ")` - split the 5th column into pieces separated by space

Comment: This works as well, and for all users even better! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

print all last names from /etc/passwd:

```
awk -F':' '{sub(/.* /,"",$5);$0=$5}7' /etc/passwd
```

In output:

```
(empty) -> ''(empty)
first middle last -> last
nickname -> nickname
```

**Some more info, may relate (or not) to this question:**

I don't think you want to get the last name from system reserved users. Like root, or daemon...

Linux (I saw the tag) has **usually** user id > 1000, if you created user by useradd. Thus you can just add `awk -F':' '$2>=1000{sub(.....'` so that those system user won't be printed out.

I said **usually** above, because some POSIX system has 500 defined. You can find out the value from your `/etc/login.defs`

It is also easy to let awk read this file and find out the min user id then check it in `/etc/passwd`, if it really required.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk F: '/smith/{print substr($5,7,5)}' /etc/passwd
Simon
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.